# D3 unusual stacked bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, stacked

I need to do an unusual stacked bar chart and acutally, i have no real idea how to do it.

In general it sounds really easy:

I have a CSV file with different values who can either be int or string. Each row has the same amount of values.

I now need to do a stacked bar chart who does the following:

-One bar for every column
-Every column needs to have the same height (cause same amount of entries for each column)
And EACH bar needs to have a different amount of stacks, one stack for every different value which exists. (The more often a value exists, the larger this stack should be)

An example CSV file would be:

```
Day, Value
Mo, 5
Mo, 3
Tu, 5
Tu, 6
```

So for the Day row i need 2 stacks the same height and for the Value row 3 stacks where one is 1/2 height and the two other 1/4 each.

And that's the problem which i have. Every example i can find on the internet works with the same amount of stacks for each bar. (For example: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886394 or https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1134768)

Any sugestions how i can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle each column as a separate stack and position them in your chart. This fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gwhn1sgv/2/ shows how.

The data for i. e. the first column need to be transformed to a histogram like this:

```
var column = 'Day';
var histo = { Mo: 2, Tu: 2 }
```

Then you can stack and transform them:

```
var keys = Object.keys(histo);
var stack = d3.stack()
  .keys(keys)([histo])
  //unpack the column
  .map((d, i) => {
    return {key: keys[i], data: d[0]}
  });
```

so they look like this:

```
var stack = [
    { key: 'Mo', data: [0, 2] },
    { key: 'Tu', data: [2, 4] }
]
```

If you have a band scale

```
var x = d3.scaleBand()
   .domain(data.columns);
```

you can build the bar chart column at `x(column)`:

```
chart.append('g')
  .selectAll('rect')
  .data(stack)
  .enter().append('rect')
     // position in the x-axis
    .attr('x', x(column))
    .attr('y', d => y(d.data[0]))
    .attr("height", d => y(d.data[1]) - y(d.data[0]))
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth());
```

Comment: thank you very much! i'll try to implent this tomorrow but it seems to solve my problem

Comment: Hey, me again...
I have two more questions and after trying for a day i give up.

First:
let's say i have a bigger csv file with 10-20 columns, and i want to build it with only 4-5 specific columns, how can i filter which columns i want to use?

I tried with:
 `d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(d) { return d.match(/.../); }) `
but i don't really know where i have to implement this. I think right at the beginning but how?

And Second: Is there a possibility to add a little "space" between each stack? 
Actually i really want to do this on my own but it seems i'm to dull for d3..

Comment: 1. Add `data.columns.filter()` directly after loading the csv to `data` and before the `for...of` loop. (line 2 in the fiddle) 2. Use the `x.padding()` method, like in the fiddle, line 6.

Comment: 1: If i simply add the line `data.columns.filter(function(d) {return d.match(/Day/);});`to the second line in the fiddle, nothing happens. If i write `data=data.columns.filter(function(d) {return d.match(/Day/);});`or `data2=...`(and replacing data with data2 everywhere) i get the error: _Unable to get property 'length' of undefinied  or null reference_   and if i log data.columns it is undefinied. That was the error i was stuck the entire time..
2: Sorry that was bad formulated, what i meant was: adding a little padding to z so that the different stacks of each row aren't directly adjacent.